# Django OneToOneField with db_index=False vs OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

As I know `OneToOneField` will create a `unique-constraint` and database will create `unique-index` to manage unique values for the `unique-constraint` internally.

As the result, `unique-constraint` would be equivalent with `unique-index`.
(because both have a `unique-index` table)

What if `models.OneToOneField('one_to_one', db_index=False)`?

`OneToOneField` needs `unique-index` to manage `unique-constraint` but It tells not to create `db_index`.

It seems weird for me, there isn't any syntax error though.

How does it work?

How is it different between `models.OneToOneField('one_to_one', db_index=False)` and `models.OneToOneField('one_to_one')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OneToOneField` implies that `unique=True` (as you can see explicitly in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5e3463f6bcec818431f0e1f4649d6a5bd944c459/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1010)), and `unique=True` implies that `db_index=True`, as noted in the documentation:

> Note that when `unique` is `True`, you don’t need to specify `db_index`, because `unique` implies the creation of an index.

So your `db_index=False` is silently ignored. One could argue that a warning should be raised in this situation.

Note that there is an [accepted ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24082) to allow both `unique=True` and `db_index=False` in some situations, but this wouldn't be one of them.

Answer (score 3):

looking at the [source code for OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/#OneToOneField) it will always set a `UNIQUE` constraint on the table.  this will  override (silently, apparently) any `db_index` preference you might have set

if you want other ways to see what's going on, here are a couple of options:

1. you could use the [`sqlmigrate` Django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) on the resulting migration to see what it'll tell your database to do
2. once you've performed the migration, you can inspect the database to see what constraints / indexes have been set up